# Cannot alter the table to set a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

When I am trying to add a foreign key to my column I am getting an error. Please let me know what is wrong with it.

```
ALTER TABLE address
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_employeeid
FOREIGN KEY (employeeid) REFERENCES newdb(employeeid);
```

Error:

> 1005 - Can't create table `mydb`.`#sql-1cc_564` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Can we see your `CREATE TABLE` statements ?

Comment: I created it from phpMyadmin

Comment: Do you really have a _table_ called _newdb_?

Comment: Yes i have all the data in that DB.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but are you sure your `employeeid` and your `newdb(employeeid)` share the same type ?

Comment: yes. i checked all of those. Still i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that `newdb` is a schema name and not a table name.
I would expect something like

```
ALTER TABLE address
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_employeeid
FOREIGN KEY (employeeid) REFERENCES newdb.Employees(employeeid);
```